# how to implement code to facebook login in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use the button to log in with facebook in my application but in a section of changing the quick access in the user profile, despite putting the privacy link it does not allow me to do it, there is a shorter and less laborious way to do a login with facebook?

Comment: Facebook no longer exists. You cannot login something non existent

Comment: There are multiple SDK's to help you with Facebook authentication. If you want help with your specific code, please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Obviously Facebook still exists. Heck, the docs for developers working with Facebook is developers.facebook.com . I assume you're referencing the companies overall rebrand to Meta. However, that rebrand left the Facebook "product" intact. A common mistake.